# Processing Error : The BROWSE action is not supported on the current platform

Tags: java, ubuntu, processing

i'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and i tried running my "Processing" IDE 3.3.7 last version and i don't know how to solve this, java Error! If anyone have an idea ?

[image: Error]

Comment: This issue in the processing github repository https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/6002

Answer (score 1):

Googling "The BROWSE action is not supported on the current platform" returns a ton of results that explain what's going on.

It sounds like Ubuntu does not support the `Desktop.browse()` function (info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI))), which I'm guessing the Processing editor uses to launch a browser when you run your sketch.

I recommend just using a different editor, and then launching your browser manually. Alternatively you could use the online [P5.js editor](https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/). Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/editors) is a tutorial on P5.js editors.

Comment: I knew all of that ! But this is unfixable ?